# Android VideoView with MediaController - how to disable seeking while streaming

Tags: android, video

If playing a video from the device, the media player knows its exact lenght and fast-forwarding through the video by moving the thumb in the mediacontroller seekbar is seemless.
If playing a streaming video from the internet, the length of the video is unknown and seeking using the thumb causes the video to stop responding.

I want to know how can I disable the thumb until the video is fully buffered? Then show it and enable fast-forwarding.

Following is my video player code:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_fragment_video_fullscreen);
    vvVideoFullscreen = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvVideoFullscreen);
    rlVideoFullscreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlVideoFullscreen);
    videoUri = Uri.parse(video.getUrl());
    vvVideoFullscreen.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(vvVideoFullscreen);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(vvVideoFullscreen);
    vvVideoFullscreen.setMediaController(mediaController);
    vvVideoFullscreen.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            rlVideoFullscreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vvVideoFullscreen.start();
            mediaController.show(3000);
        }
    });

vVideoFullscreen.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            finish();

        }
    });

    vvVideoFullscreen.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (vvVideoFullscreen.isPlaying()) {

                    vvVideoFullscreen.pause();
                    mediaController.hide();

                } else {

                    vvVideoFullscreen.start();
                    mediaController.show();

                }

            }
            return true;
        }

    }); // End of setOnTouchListener
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding an `onBufferingUpdateListener()` to your `mediaplayer`?
From the documentation is says:

```
public abstract void onBufferingUpdate (MediaPlayer mp, int percent)
```

> Called to update status in buffering a media stream received through
>   progressive HTTP download. The received buffering percentage indicates
>   how much of the content has been buffered or played. For example a
>   buffering update of 80 percent when half the content has already been
>   played indicates that the next 30 percent of the content to play has
>   been buffered.

So when this callback is invoked with 100%, you know your video is fully buffered.

To disable all playback controls, you can simply only call `mediaController.setMediaPlayer(...)` when buffering is completed.

If you want to only disable the seek thumb, I suggest to implement your own `MediaController.MediaPlayerControlInterface` and rout all calls to your `MediaPlayer` object. Seeking can then be disabled by having the `canSeekForward()` and `canSeekBackward()` methods return false and by making the `seekTo(int pos)` method don't do anything on your MediaPlayer.

Comment: this is a good idea, but how do I disable the seek thumb and then enable it in onBufferingUpdate?

Comment: Added two different ways on how you could do that

Comment: Thank you I will try that as soon as I can and get back to you